# Лук и лекало — этимологически однокоренные?

Tags: этимология

Относятся ли слова лук (для стрельбы) и лекало к однокоренным?

Answer (score 3):

1. Вот что есть у Фасмера.

[**лук**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-7117.htm)
род. п. -а, II. (для стрельбы), укр. лук. ст.-слав. лѫкъ τόξον (Супр.), болг. лък, сербохорв. лу̑к, род. п. лу̑ка, словен. **lǫ̑k**, чеш. luk, польск. **ɫęk "дуга, арка, лука".**
Родственно лит. lañkas "дуга, обруч", lankùs "гибкий", лтш. lùoks "изгиб, дуга", luôks "гибкий"; с другой ступенью вокализма: лит. **leñkti "гнуть"**. Далее см. **ляка́ть**; ср. Бернекер 1, 739 и сл.; Траутман, ВSW 159; М.–Э. 2, 525; Эндзелин, СБЭ 196; Лескин, Abl. 324; Bildg. 168; Булаховский, ОЛЯ 5, 470.

[**лека́ло**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-6803.htm)
II. "модель, образец, шаблон; кривая линейка для черчения; колодка на ноги северного оленя".
Вероятно, **из *лѧкати "гнуть"**, т. е. **"образец, по которому что-либо выгибается"**; см. Преобр. I, 445. Не от лить, вопреки Горяеву (ЭС 184). Последнее знач. ср. со след.

2. Вот что пишет Л. В. Успенский:
   **Лека́ло.** Древнерусское «лѧкати» («ѧ» — носовой звук) значило «сгибать» и было одного происхождения с «лук», «излучина», «лукавый». Отсюда «лекало» — то, по чему гнут, изгибают; недаром в народных говорах его кое-где именуют «гиба́ло».
3. Вот что нашлось в автореферате Л. В. Соколовской [**История слов с корнем -лук-/-ляк- в русском языке XI-XX вв. (Семантический аспект)**](http://cheloveknauka.com/istoriya-slov-s-kornem-luk-lyak-v-russkom-yazyke-xi-xx-vv-semanticheskiy-aspekt). В данной работе исследуется история развития семантики слов с корнем -лук-/-ляк- с первоначальным значением "изгиб" в русском языке ХI-ХХ вв.

Во втором разделе первой главы "Бытовая лексика" рассматриваются лексемы, входящие в группу "предметы обихода". К данной группе отнесены слова, имеющие предметное значение: 'изгиб' - 'предмета'.
Слова с общим значением "предметы обихода", в свою очередь, могут быть подразделены на несколько СГ [семантических групп]:
**1)** оружие (**лук**, лучник, налучъ, лучишко, лучонко, луконосец, лучейная и др.);
2) изгиб седла (лук, лука, слука, облук);
3) изгиб ремня, веревки (лукость, лукота, лукоть);
4) сиденье саней (облук, лучок, облучок, лука, облак, облако и др.);
**5)** модель для изгиба (**лекало**, лекальщик, лекальная);
6) тара для чего-либо (лукошко, лукно, лукошечко, луконце и др.).

Думаю, что эта информация позволяет сделать вывод: *лук* и *лекало* ― это этимологически родственные слова.